# Stop Subform Requery with Multiple Users in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a very simple form with a combo box that is populated by a query. A user selects the class for which they want to enter data from the combo box and the records (passing the selection from the combo box to another query) for that class are loaded into a subform.

However, when multiple users are accessing the database and another teacher selects another class from the dropdown and starts entering data, the subform for the first teacher requeries and brings up the class selected by the other teacher.

How do I avoid this?

I have split the database into frontend and backend.

Comment: Has each user got their own front-end?

Comment: As far as I know. Initially, I had each user accessing the front-end from a shared network drive. However, I then tried copying the front-end onto the desktop of two separate computers to see if that fixed it, but it doesn't seem to have.

Comment: Double check two front-ends and make sure you are not using a query stored on the back-end.

Comment: The query isn't stored on the back-end. I believe I have two front-ends. I did the database split process then copied the front-end onto users local drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that the combobox for selecting the class is bound to a field in a table. That is why it is updating for one user when another user makes a selection.

You should make this combobox unbound (=clear the `ControlSource` property).

It is not clear to me if you are already doing this, but the correct way of filtering by a field (class in your case) is to set `LinkMasterFields` (of the subform control) to the name of your combox control and `LinkChildFields` to the class field in the the underlying recordset of the the subform.